# Как сделать доли секунды в регулярке опциональными?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, jaxb

Как сделать доли секунды и таймзону в шаблоне опциональными?

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z"
```

Использую в

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
```

Все это пытаюсь сделать для класса

```
public class DateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS Z");

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.format(v);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        synchronized (dateFormat) {
            return dateFormat.parse(v);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В какой регулярке, где это используется? если они тебе не нужны просто не указывай их

Comment: Возможно, нужно использовать `(...)?`, где `...` — опциональный участок регулярного выражения

Comment: @Keeplod обновил вопрос

Comment: Вы регулярку в `SimpleDateFormat` писали? А что будет если придет строка датывремени без долей секунд? Исключение?

Comment: @gil9red, да, писал внутри SimpleDateFormat. Если без долей секунд приходит сейчас, то да исключение. Мне как раз и нужно, чтобы доли - секунды были опциональны.

Comment: Сделайте два варианта вызова парсинга с SimpleDateFormat -- один с миллимекундами и второй без. И оберните вызов одного из SimpleDateFormat в try / catch. Т.е. пробуете распарсить и если произошло исключение в catch пробуйте другим шаблоном. Регулярки тут только код усложнят

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приходящую дату проверить на наличие долей секунд (как я понял - это точка + 3 цифры)

```
if (date.matches(".*(\\.(\d){3}){1}z") {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
} else {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
}
```

Comment: Точно в else должен попадать **любой** текст, не соответствующий регулярному выражению?

Comment: @cppquestions Здесь зависит от приложения и входных данных. Я бы сделал проверки, но думаю моего примера достаточно, чтобы автору вопроса был понятен смысл реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал вот такой метод, который преобразовывал строку в дату.

```
public static Date getDateFromString(String value, boolean silent) {
    Map<String, String> formatsMap = ImmutableMap.of(
            "\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}", "dd.MM.yyyy",
            "\\d{1,2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}\\s+\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",
            "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}", "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}\\s+\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
            String trimmedValue = value.trim();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : formatsMap.entrySet()) {
                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(entry.getKey());
                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(trimmedValue);
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    return new SimpleDateFormat(entry.getValue()).parse(value);
                }
            }
        }
        if (silent) {
            return null;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неподдерживаемый формат даты!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (silent) {
            return null;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Неподдерживаемый формат даты!");
    }
}
```

Можно добавить в `formatsMap` другие шаблоны даты, либо указать только те, которые вам нужны.